# Generating all leafs from a tree

Tags: c++, tree, depth-first-search

I'm trying to make a simple tree exploration script that prints all the leafs. However What I see printed is not what I expect.

For this toy example each node represents a string and has 4 children, cosisting on appending A, B, C or D to the parent string.

```
E.g for max_depth = 2:

                        ""
     A            B            C            D
AA AB AC AD  BA BB BC BD  CA CB CC CD  DA DB DC DD
```

My code:

```
void explore_tree(string sequence, int depth, int max_depth) {
    if (depth == max_depth) {
        cout << sequence << endl;
        return;
    }
    explore_tree(sequence.append("A"), depth+1, max_depth);
    explore_tree(sequence.append("B"), depth+1, max_depth);
    explore_tree(sequence.append("C"), depth+1, max_depth);
    explore_tree(sequence.append("D"), depth+1, max_depth);
}

explore_tree("", 0, 2);
```

Basically when I reach max_depth I print the sequence. 
Otherwise I do recursion appending A, B, C or D to the current sequence

I would expect to see the list of leafs, but instead I see more things concatenated:

```
AA
AAB
AABC
AABCD
ABA
ABAB
ABABC
ABABCD
ABCA
ABCAB
ABCABC
ABCABCD
ABCDA
ABCDAB
ABCDABC
ABCDABCD
```

Am I missing something? I cannot see why this doesn't output the expected result.

Comment: `string.append` modifies the original string. Aside: plural of _leaf_ is _leaves_.

Comment: Oh, true! Thanks